# How can I enable RECURSIVE CTE in Chrome Sqlite + WebSql?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-chrome, common-table-expression, web-sql

I am currently working with a WEBSQL database in Chrome.

I have some sample code which uses a chrome based WebSQL database with recursive CTE (it can be easily pasted into a the developer javascript console to validate)

```
/* Open Database */
var db = window.openDatabase("MyTestDB", "1", "1", 5e6),
/* function that you can execute with any sql  */
testSql = function(sql){
    db.transaction(function _go(tx){
        tx.executeSql(sql, [], done, done);
    })
},
done = function(){ console.log(arguments) },
/* Sample CTE */
cte_not_broken = `WITH RECURSIVE cnt(x) AS 
                (SELECT 1
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 2)
               SELECT * FROM cnt;`
cte_broken = `WITH RECURSIVE cnt(x) AS 
                (SELECT 1
                UNION ALL
                SELECT x+1 FROM cnt LIMIT 10)
               SELECT * FROM cnt;`

testSql(cte_not_broken)
/* returns a SQLResultSet
// { x: 1, x: 2 }  */
testSql(cte_broken)
/* returns a SQLError
// { code: 5, 
//   message: "could not prepare statement (23 not authorized)" } */
testSql("SELECT sqlite_version()")
/* returns a SQLResultSet
// { sqlite_version(): "3.8.7.4" } */
```

If I run these same queries in the Sqlite Manager firefox extension these CTE queries *do* work.  If I run them on a device (android/cordova using a SqlitePlugin) they queries *do* work.

Is there any way within Chrome to enable CTE?

Comment: You'd have to update the SQLite library to at least version 3.8.3.

Comment: Is 3.8.7.4 (the version in chrome as of this writing) was released after 3.8.3.  I *think* there is something going on with compiler flags.

Comment: Then you have to recompile Chrome with other [compilation options](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html).